# Span of $\{\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^2}, \frac{1}{x^3}...\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The set above is a linearly independent set.

So if we are in the vector space containing all functions from $(50, \infty)$ into $\mathbb{R}$, we want to determine if the span of the set is V.

I keep hearing about using a constant, where eventually I will get

$kx^n = c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{n-2} + ... + c_n$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$

I can't seem to see the connection here. Even if I rearrange and use the fact that ${x^n, x^{n-1}, ... }$ is linearly independent with all constants = 0, doesn't that mean that $k$ is a constant that works anyways?

Comment: All functions?  Certainly no discontinuous function is in your span.

Comment: "we want to determine if the span of the set is V" - what is V?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the difference between constants and coefficients.

Comment: @GEdgar That's true. I was originally thinking of tan($x$).

Comment: lisyarus, It was outlined in the second line.
JessicaK, It turns out I was..

Answer (score 1):

1. Denote the set of your rational functions by $S$
2. A constant function $1$ is in $V$.
3. Suppose that this function is spanned by your set $S$. Then there exist a finite number of powers $k_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and corresponding coefficients $a_i$ $i=1,\ldots,n$ such that

$$1 = a_1 x^{-k_1} + a_2 x^{-k_2}+\cdots + a_n x^{-k_n}\quad \forall x>50.$$

Now multiply everything by $x^N$ where $N=k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n$:
$$0=-x^N + a_1 x^{N-k_1} + a_2 x^{N-k_2}+\cdots + a_n x^{N-k_n}\quad \forall x>50.$$

Therefore, you have a polynomial of degree $N>1$ having infinite number of roots (in fact, all points $x>50$ are roots). Therefore, this polynomial is identically zero, which contradicts the fact the coefficient at $x^N$ is $-1$.

Therefore the constant function $1$ is not spanned by your set $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W$ be the space of functions $(0,\frac1{50})\to\Bbb R$. Then $V\to W$, $f\mapsto (x\mapsto f(1/x))$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces (intriguingly with $f\mapsto (x\mapsto f(1/x))$ as inverse). As $\frac1{x^k}$ maps to $x^k$, the span of the $\frac1{x^k}$ is not all of $V$ just as the span of all $x^k$, $k\ge 1$ is only the subspace of polynomials having a root at $0$, much less than all of $W$.